# ‘LaTeX’ logo with kerning issue and not scaling properly

Tags: fontsize, small-caps, kerning, libertine, logos

I recently discovered that the `\LaTeX` command does not have proper kerning between the first ‘L’ and the ‘A’, the ‘A’ looks too thin (like fake smallcaps, simple downscaling). Also the logo doesn't scale properly when choosing the `\tiny` font size (the A gets out of proportion). I use the `libertine` package, so Linux Libertine. How to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
\centering
{\tiny\LaTeX}

\LaTeX

{\Huge\LaTeX}
\end{document}
```

[image: bad LaTeX logo]

Comment: Just to be clear, `\TeX` and `\LaTeX` are commands designed with respect to the Computer Modern font. Some ad hoc tweaking is needed to make the logos look equally good with other fonts.

Comment: @Sverre: Sure, but IMO it's bad design that the ‘A’ is chosen as a one step smaller font (my theory) is showing through when selecting the `\tiny` size, as then no smaller step is available for the A to have. I consider this as a kind of bug that I found here. Small caps is just the better choice for that A and the `metalogo` developer agrees.

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual use case is. You may want to consider loading the `graphicx` package and typing `\scalebox{0.5}{\LaTeX}` to get a logo that's scaled 50% linearly from the original.

Comment: @Mico: The `\tiny` is just to show the deficiency and is not an actual use case for me, but normal size is and I find my solution to look better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `metalogo`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}

% keep the original for reference
\usepackage{letltxmacro,xpatch}
\LetLtxMacro\oldLaTeX\LaTeX
\LetLtxMacro\oldTeX\TeX
\xpatchcmd{\oldLaTeX}{\TeX}{\oldTeX}{}{\ddt}

\usepackage{metalogo}

\setLaTeXa{\scshape a}
\setlogokern{La}{-.3em}
\setlogokern{aT}{-.1em}
\setlogokern{Te}{-.08em}
\setlogokern{eX}{-.1em}
\setlogodrop{0.33ex}

\begin{document}

{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\oldLaTeX}

\LaTeX

{\tiny\LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Without digging into the code, it seems that the `\LaTeX` logo chooses a one step smaller font size for the ‘A’, and thus when encountering `\tiny` there is no smaller step available, destroying the proportions. I think this is as close to finding a bug in the (La)TeX system as I will ever get  ;). Small caps is just the logical choice for that A, it fits in beautifully, but they might not be available for a different typeface.

I defined a new command `\myLaTeX` which uses the small caps provided by Linux Libertine for the ‘A’ and has the proper kerning between the letters. The spacing is font size dependent using `em` for horizontal and `ex` for vertical spacing. As the screenshot shows, it behaves nicely with different font sizes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\DeclareRobustCommand\myLaTeX{%
    L\kern-.3em%
    \raisebox{.4ex}{\scshape a}\kern-.13em%
    T\kern-.2em%
    \raisebox{-.5ex}{E}\kern-.13em%
    X%
}

\begin{document}
\centering
{\tiny\LaTeX\ \myLaTeX}

\LaTeX\ \myLaTeX

{\Huge\LaTeX\ \myLaTeX}
\end{document}
```

[image: nice LaTeX logo]

Alternatively, the package [`metalogo`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/metalogo) can adjust the TeX logos, which is often needed, for many fonts. It would be possible to fix the kerning and the weight of the ‘A’, but I'm not sure about the scaling behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently writing a new package `flexlogo` which addresses this for different fonts. It's not on CTAN yet but anyone wishing to test it and let me know of bugs is welcome to contact me at peter@silmaril.ie

Comment: How does the package go? Is it ready yet?

Comment: No, I abandoned it in favour of the metalogo package mentioned above. I must apologise for not having mentioned this here earlier.